# Can I access the AuthenticateResult.Fail exception parameter in other middleware?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware

In my AuthenticationHandler I have some (shared) code like:

```
 try
    {
       doSomething()
    }
    catch(AuthException e)
    {
        return AuthenticateResult.Fail(e);
    }
```

I would like to be able to access that exception in other middleware. something like :

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
 context.   ??? AuthenticationContext.Exception?
}
```